# What happen if two sql table have the same column name while trying to write a sql query from the two?

Tags: mysql, sql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ2Pi.png

If i were to write a sql query based of the "pid" from Research Project and Time records. Would the pid simply merge together or do i have to input two separate pid query when using both table?

Here is a example of what i mean, a sql query to find out what the names of projects and the total number of hours.

```
select title, workhours    
from researchproject,timerecords  
where pid IN (48,149,199)
```

^ would this be able to work? since there could be a massive corruption if two table have the same column name as a result they were not be able to merge for the final result.

or maybe a recursion method probably not necessary :

```
where pid IN (48,149,199)
or pid IN (48,149,199)
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff `FROM researchproject a,timerecords b WHERE a.sid = b.sid` can this be more efficient than using `JOIN`  ?

Comment: You need to join both tables on `pid`, currently you get all rows from the 1st table joined to all rows from the 2nd table, i.e. n*m rows.

Comment: @ali: Both are exactly the same join, just implicit vs. explicit, and both are still valid Standard SQL (but most people prefer the JOIN syntax).

Comment: @dnoeth my professor told me that try not to use `JOIN` keyword for joining tables

Comment: @ali: How old is your professor? Does he tell you to program in Assembler and Cobol using punch cards, too? Standard SQL 92 introduced the JOIN syntax, 25 years ago, enough time to get used to it.

Comment: he is actually very good in his job , maybe I miss understand his advice

Comment: A part of your question is how to differentiate between the same column names in different tables. Well, you can by prefixiing your column-name with the tablename and a dot (this may differ per sql-flavour): firsttable.pid, and secondtable.pid

Comment: Thanks for help guys , not sure about the join syntax since comma still work the same as join. FROM researchproject a,timerecords b WHERE a.sid = b.sid - this seem to does the trick.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all    im using this to test it and it work.

Comment: @UmikaLuciole and what happens if you need to join several tables, some via outer joins, with complex filters? If both your join criteria and your filters are in the whereclause, then your query will be a lot less readable. If you mix comma syntax with outer joins, then you will quickly realise that the comma syntax and explicit joins are not entirely the same. So, take Gordon's advice and forget the comma syntax.